# Slide new items into a list

Tags: jquery, slide, slidedown, slideup

I have a list of links I'm getting from the server, via AJAX, and I'm updating it with the new links I get from the server. I want the list to slide down and the new servers to slide on top.

My list is a div containing a list of paragraphs containing a link each, and I'm trying to add a new link on top.

I've tried things I've seen in other posts, like

```
link = $('<p id="div1_p_5"><a id="div1_5" href="dummy5">dummy text 5</a></p> ');

$("#div1").prepend(link).children(':first').hide().slideDown(1000);
```

but the new link either appears and makes the rest to go down and up suddenly (it seems that it appears with a big margin and takes a little time to fall back to the stylesheet) or just appears instantly without animation.

I'm using paragraphs because the same happened with an item link and I found some old post saying it was a jQ bug with item lists.

I made this jsfiddle with everything:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5qj8s/5/)

Comment: why are you using div and p with display:table instead of tables?

Comment: I really don't care what kind the elements are, I just need a list of entries, as long as the entries are single lines including links and maybe a couple of spans. I used <p> because that's the only way I could make an example work with slideUp() and slideDown(). I'm kind of new to web design, it's the second site I design and the first one was kind of simple, so I'm not really sure which ones is "the way to go" with an updating list. I tried <ul> and just adding the  content to new <li>, which seemed the most adequate thing, but I read somewhere that slideUp/Down had a bug with <ul>'s

Answer (score 0):

use style in element to hide it before inserting:

```
link = $('<p id="div1_p_5" style="display:none"><a id="div1_5" href="dummy5">dummy text 5</a></p> ');
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried your code and it worked just fine. you can try this one for the second line, with the actions in different order

```
link.hide().prependTo('#div1').slideDown(1000);
```

Comment: really? I'm trying it in jsfiddle and the new line just appears, without animation: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5qj8s/5/)

Comment: apparently the conflict is with div p{display:table}, with display:block it works fine